# StyleService.unregisterSheet fail without error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to unregister stylesheet:

```
try {
     var StyleService = Cc["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
     StyleService.unregisterSheet(url, StyleService.USER_SHEET);
} catch (e){
    console.log(e);
}

var isRegistered = StyleService.sheetRegistered(url, StyleService.USER_SHEET);
if (isRegistered) {
    console.log("styleSheet unregister check is failed url:" + url.path);
}
```

One stylesheet i generate `Services.io.newURI("data:text/css,"+ encodeURIComponent(content), null, null);`
And it unregisters fine. But another file located on ProfD directory fails on `isRegistered` check.

```
var styleFile = FileUtils.getFile(FS.ProfileName, [FS.DirName, this.CSS_FILE_PATH]);
this.injectCssUrl = IoService.newFileURI(styleFile).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL);
```

Why it unregister?

Answer (score 1):

```
var sss = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
var ios = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
try {
sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
} catch (ex) {}

var css = 'setting .preferences-alignment{ display:flex; flex-direction:row-reverse; align-items:center; }';
//var cssEnc = 'data:text/css;base64,' + window.btoa(css);
var cssEnc = encodeURIComponent(css);
var cssUri = makeURI('data:text/css,' + cssEnc);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

if you want to use a file then something like

```
var appliedURI;

function startup(aData, aReason) {
var path = aData.resourceURI.spec + 'no_icon.css'; //or in your case styleFile.path
appliedURI = Services.io.newURI(path, null, null);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(appliedURI, sss.USER_SHEET);
}

function shutdown(aData, aReason) {
if (aReason == APP_SHUTDOWN) return;
sss.unregisterSheet(appliedURI, sss.USER_SHEET);
}
```

Comment: where to declare startup function? is it exports.main = function (options, callbacks) {

Comment: oh no need for that, that was just a copy paste out of an addon to show you ho wto use file.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that i register the same style several times. After i unregister style each time before register again all works normaly

Comment: i would think there is logic error somehwere, you're doing things fine. make sure you are checking right sheet, no references held global var on accdient etc